# How to define my own custom UIColor?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

Is there a mean in SWIFT to define my own custom color? and call it with:

```
mybutton.backgroundColor = UIColor.mycustomcolor
```

I need to use mycustomcolor many times in my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
extension UIColor {

    static let myCustomColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

}
```

Comment: Why define it as a computed property when it can be a stored property as well? Simply do `static let myCustomColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)`

Comment: @DávidPásztor Good idea, thanks